# describe all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $-1 \in \left \langle 2 \right \rangle \leq (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^x $

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

I would like to describe (in a lower level of abstraction) the set $N = \left \{n \in \mathbb{N} : -1 \in \left \langle 2 \right \rangle \leq (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^x \right \} $.

Clearly $N \subseteq \mathbb{N}_{odd}$. (This set is actually well defined only for odd $n$'s)

Also i heard that $\mathbb{P} \subseteq N$ but not sure how to prove it. (**EDIT** this is not true, since $-1 \notin \left \{ 1,2,4 \right \} = \left \langle 2 \right \rangle  \leq (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^x$).

Is there more to it? Here are some questions i am trying to answer, yet any other information regarding the set $N$ is wanted:

1) Is $N$ infinite?

2) Can we find a set $M$ such that $N \subset M \subset \mathbb{N}_{odd} $

3) Can we describe the set $N$ more directly?

Comment: The sentence starting with "Furthermore" is wrong

Comment: Please use $R^{\times}$ or $R^*$ to denote the unit group of a ring $R$. I understood your notation as a direct sum of $x$ copies of $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ and got rather confused.

Comment: oh right, the order is one less than a prime, thanks..

Comment: @Servaes I meant something else: $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^x$ = the multiplicative group of integers modulo n = all the multiplicative invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That is precisely the unit group of the ring $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, we mean the same thing.

Comment: But $7 \not\in N$.

Comment: I see. my misunderstanding, sorry. I described it that way because it is referred to as a group rather than as a ring. I'm not sure if it will be clear if I denote it as a ring. Will it?

Comment: This seems difficult! If we restrict attention to primes $p$, then $p \in N$ if $p \equiv 3,5 \bmod 8$ and $p \not\in N$ if $p \equiv 7 \bmod 8$. (So $N$ is infinite.) If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ then $p$ is usually but not always in $N$. For example $73 \not\in N$  because $2$ has odd order ($9$) mod $73$.

Comment: @DerekHolt  can you explain the proof to that? And yes I totally agree it should be limited to primes.. at least at first, thanks. Working on a more concrete question.

Answer (score 1):

let's restrict attention to the case when $n=p$ is prime. Then the multiplicative group $(Z/pZ)^\times$ is cyclic and $-1$ is its only element of order $2$. So $-1 \in \langle 2 \rangle$ if and only if $2$ has even order in $(Z/pZ)^\times$.

Now it is well known that $2$ is a square in $(Z/pZ)^\times$ if and only if $p \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 8$.

So if $p \equiv \pm3 \bmod 8$, then $2$ is not a square, and so it must have even order, and hence $-1 \in \langle 2 \rangle$.

If $p \equiv -1 \bmod 8$, then $2$ is a square, and the $(Z/pZ)^\times$ has twice off order, so $2$ has odd order, and $-1 \not\in \langle 2 \rangle$.

I don't know exactly what happens when $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$. Calculating this for small $p$ suggests that $-1 \in  \langle 2 \rangle$ is usually but not always true. It is false for $p=73$, for example.

By the way, I think this question is as much Number Theory as Group Theory, so I will add Number Theory to the tags.